# Spring MVC Model Attributes lost on use of Browser back button

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Currently we are populating the following method with flashattributes which seem to be working initially but if we hit a link to leave the site and then hit the back button  then all of the model attributes are lost. Is there a way to remember all the model attributes on back?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/confirm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showConfirm(HttpSession session, ModelMap model) {
    return "products/confirm";
}
```

Comment: FlashAttributes are only available for one request. If you hit the back button, another GET request is made (unless the page is cached) and the flash attributes are no longer accessible. What is your specific use case? I assume that you are adding flash attributes and then performing redirect to the /confirm page?

Comment: Yes I am just doing a redirect to the confirm page, but it looks like the flash attributes are populating the model which I though would get saved?

Comment: FlashAttributes are stored in a FlashMap (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FlashMap.html) which is cleared after the redirect. I don't know if it's the best solution (probably not) but you could use redirectAttributes.addAttribute() instead of addFlashAttributes(). That way the data will be available on the confirm page as request params.

Comment: Well they are large objects so I am not sure that solution would work but if that is my only choice I may be able to change round what we pass in to make that work.